# Unable to input a correct location in careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Tampere, Finland is a location. Tampere Theatre, Finland is a building.

I am unable to select Tampere, Finland as a location I am willing to relocate at. I do not want to live in Tampere Theatre. I'm scared of phantoms. `;)`

I admit the building is at a certain location, but Tampere is not really that big place that it'd be necessary to split it up in smaller parts.

I wish I would at least be able to override it somehow.

Comment: +1 Simply because you're Finnish.

Comment: Blame Yahoo! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'd blame yahoo, but they did not restrict the field so that I can not override the value. I still believe that users know better than machines where they live / want to live.

Comment: @Lasse true but having free text is risk as the system won't be able to find the location and give it unique coords.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT:

Seems to have resolved itself.

---

Seems like this is actually a blame Yahoo situation.

[Yahoo Maps](http://maps.yahoo.com/place/?lat=61.49781&lon=23.76226&q=tempere%20finland&bb=61.61317087459348%2C23.613291820068362%2C61.382449125406524%2C23.91122817993164&addr=Tampere%20Theatre%2C%20Finland)
[YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+geo.places+where+text%3D%22tampere+finland%22)

I see in our name search cache that people have tried including the postal code, region codes and other values I dont quite understand to get the desired result, but none of those seem to help.  I could manually change this, but I cannot guarantee it would stay with what I changed it to.

In terms of usability on the site, I understand the name thing sucks, but it shouldn't affect any of the functionality that uses this value because the issue is happening everywhere on the site.

I have opened a [bug report](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/-BUG-REPORT-Tampere-Finland-is-a/1381936985739-d72b5a54-b1ce-4be6-86aa-e77fa7ab87c6?msg=1) on the YQL forums regarding this issue and I will update this post and all associated records once it is addressed.

Comment: Any update, 6-8 weeks later?

Comment: Looks like it's working properly now: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?searchTerm=&location=tampere

Comment: Cheers @rla4 missed that comment and saw it by chance now. Nick, it was probably fixed by Yahoo, isn't it? So we need their dev to show up and get some hard earned Meta rep. :D